# aggregating on a shifted 24H window

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following example

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'var' : np.random.randint(0,10, size = 16993)},
             index = pd.date_range('2021-01-01 00:00:00',
                                   '2021-03-01 00:00:00',
                                   freq ='5 min'))
df.head(10)
Out[272]: 
                     var
2021-01-01 00:00:00    5
2021-01-01 00:05:00    9
2021-01-01 00:10:00    1
2021-01-01 00:15:00    5
2021-01-01 00:20:00    8
```

This is a classic dataframe with intraday data. I need to aggregate it at the daily level, but I do not want to use the 24 hours from `00:00:00` to `23:59:59` that would be implicitly used if I ran `df.groupby(df.index.date)`

```
df.groupby(df.index.date).agg('sum').head()
Out[274]: 
             var
2021-01-01  1440
2021-01-02  1238
2021-01-03  1274
2021-01-04  1277
2021-01-05  1253
```

Rather, I want to aggregate using a 24H windows that starts at `1:00:00` every day. So the first group will be between `2021-01-01 01:00:00` and `2021-02-01 00:59:59`, the second between `2021-02-01 01:00:00` and `2021-03-01 00:59:59`, and so on.  The starting times can easily be identified, as shown below.

```
df['flag'] = df.index.time == datetime.time(1,0)
```

What is the best way to proceed to create the groups?
Thanks!

Comment: How about upsampling to time units and then aggregating to 24 line units? `df = df.resample('H').sum()[1:];df.reset_index(inplace=True);df.groupby(df.index // 24).sum()` Now we need to figure out how to add the date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [`Resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with `offset`

The offset parameter is the `Timedelta` that can be added to the origin to create custom grouping intervals

```
df.resample('D', offset=pd.Timedelta(hours=1)).sum()
```

---

```
                      var
2020-12-31 01:00:00    72
2021-01-01 01:00:00  1278
2021-01-02 01:00:00  1301
2021-01-03 01:00:00  1291
2021-01-04 01:00:00  1346
....
```